# Where is the API documentation for boto3 resources?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have learned that `boto3` offers two levels of abstraction: a low-level API called `client` that is a thin wrapper around the AWS HTTP API, and a high-level client called `resource` that offers real Python objects. My question is, where is the API documentation for the `resource` API?

I found this:

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/services/ec2.html#client

But that describes the `client` API, and there's not a 1-to-1 mapping to the `resource` API. For example, enumerating instances is called `describe_instances()` on the `client` object, and it is called `instances.all()` on the `resource` object.

Next I found this:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/core/resources.html?highlight=resource

This describes a set of base classes and factory methods, but it doesn't describe the API for a specific service like EC2.

At runtime, I printed out an object of interest and found that it is a `boto3.resources.factory.ec2.ServiceResource`, but searching the `boto3` documentation doesn't show me any human-readable documentation for this resource.

Is there an API document that explains what all of the different Python classes are, and what properties/methods they have? I can print this out at runtime, e.g. `print(dir(ec2))` but this is a pretty tedious way to discover the API.

Comment: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/services/ec2.html#service-resource

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Thanks @jordanm for answering in the comments. I'm expanding into a more detailed answer.

The `client` documentation contains a section called "Service Resource" that I had not noticed before.

**Highlighted the service resource in the table of contents:**

[image: table of contents for client documentation]

**Clicking this heading shows me the methods and properties of an EC2 resource instance.**

[image: methods of an EC2 resource instance]

Answer (score 5):

Hope this answer is useful to some even though its late.

Use these two links accordingly

Consider the 1st one as the Main reference. This is the link provided in the other answer
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#service-resource

[Main reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUBmW.png)

The 2nd one provides a more detailed view on the methods and attributes available for a particular resource like instance,image,VPC etc

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

`^this is almost the same link -- all options below the service-resource provide detailed info on that particular resource such as instance,image etc.,`

[common resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPI2H.png)